# IWebElement becomes null after being sent to a function

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to check if my `IWebElement` is displayed or not. When I try to reach and check the `IWebElement` within the class it's all OK but when I send it to my `KontrolElement()` function I get a `NullReferenceException`. `KontrolElemet()` is required because this process takes place several times.

`KontrolElement()`:

```
//This is inside a class called 'Helpers'
public void KontrolElement(IWebDriver WebDriver, IWebElement WebElement, string msg)
{
    try
    {
        //"WebElement" is null
        Assert.IsTrue(WebElement.Displayed);
    }
    catch (AssertionException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kontrol: " + msg);

        //Sends an E-mail with the screenshot of the page attached to it
        new ScreenShot().Crush(WebDriver, msg, "");
    }
}
```

How I use it ('el' is generally an object inside an IReadOnlyCollection which is iterared with a foreach loop):

```
//This takes place in the PageObject class which extends 'Helpers'
IWebElement el = WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("listTop"));

//Console.WriteLine(el.Displayed) outputs True

KontrolElement(WebDriver, el, "el is not displayed");
```

Has anyone faced a problem like this? What can be the alternative solutions?

Comment: I think it's impossible to be null. What happen if you uncomment the `Console.WriteLine(el.Displayed)`? Do you see both  "true" and "el is not displayed" in console?

Comment: It seems there has to be more to this story, have you stepped through the whole process carefully to make sure things are being called like you're expecting? The above code in its minimalist form works, I've tested it just to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. You've got more going on then what you've shown above that is causing `KontrolElement` to be called with a null `IWebElement`.

Comment: @mrfreester I figured out that the `NullReferenceException` has something else to do with it. Also I completed `KontrolElement()` in the question and I'm certain that `NullReferenceException` is thrown inside this function.

Comment: Hi @KenanSoylu, you'll need to carefully step through your code to see exactly which `WebElement` is `null` and when it happens. There is nothing in your example that would cause it to become `null`, so there is something else your code that is causing this. Some guesses: conflicting variables, swallowed exceptions, a call to `KontrolElement` you're not expecting, etc...

Comment: Just saw your answer, that information would probably be better appended to your question. If you work with someone who writes code, ask them to help you read the stack trace or step through the code so you can see what line is failing, and which object is giving you the `NullReferenceException`. If you can share the stack trace of the error message you're seeing you'd possibly get a quick answer here as well.

Comment: @mrfreester it turns out that there is another Assert reference in the System.Debug library that I imported, I was trying to use the Assert reference which is inside the NLog library. This conflict was causing the problem.

Comment: To actually mark your question as solved, click on the check mark next to the most helpful answer. Adding SOLVED to titles is generally [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/260312)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of wrapping `Assert`s or wrapping anything so simple into a function. What do you gain? Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

Remove the function and just use the below code in your scripts

```
IWebElement el = WebDriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("listTop"));
Assert.IsTrue(el.Displayed, "Verify element is displayed");
```

I would change "element" in the assert comment to something more specific, e.g. "Verify login button is displayed".

If you insist on using the function, why are you passing in `IWebDriver` when you aren't using it?

Another thing... catching a generic `Exception` is not a good practice. Catch only what you plan to handle.

Comment: I'd +1 all of this as comments, but I'm not sure this actually answers the question? That being said, following best practices like these does reduce annoying and difficult to track bugs in code, which probably would help the OP avoid this error in the first place.

Comment: @mrfreester I think there are things in OP's function that are not included in the question otherwise the function is not the issue, he's passing in a null WebElement. I suggested fixes for other things not asked for but if he just uses the simple code that I provided in two lines, that should fix the null WebElement. If the element isn't found, it will result in another exception that then can/should lead to the issue. I think there is code not supplied that is doing something with the element and passing back a null reference.

Comment: @mrfreester If I were to guess, he's probably eating a not found exception in some code that passes back the null reference... but... we will never know unless he includes all the relevant code in the question

Comment: That is a good point, avoiding the useless wrapper takes care of the issue completely and would be a valid solution even though it doesn't address the exact problem. A problem which can't be determined with the given information.

Comment: @JeffC the reason that I'm wrapping it a try-catch inside a function is that so I could send an E-mail every time I get an Assertion Exception. You are right about the generic Exception part though.

Comment: There are many libraries like NUnit, etc. that generate reports from runs. There's no need to send an email after every exception (and I'm not sure why you would even want an email for every exception). Just execute the run and then email the final report that contains all the failures/exceptions.

Comment: @JeffC that actually makes more sense but the legacy code that I'm working on is built for this purpose. It would definitely be wise to rewrite it. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

A conflict between the `System.Debug` and `Nlog` library was causing the problem, the compiler would see the `Assert` reference in the `System.Debug` library which in return would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it had to do with the namespace. I was using `OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects`. This caused the element to be null always. Fixed the issue by using the `SeleniumExtras.PageObjects` namespace instead.